# Is there an algebraically normal function from $\mathbb{Z}^{n}$ to $\{ 0 , 1\}$?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, nt.number-theory, gr.group-theory, pr.probability, geometric-group-theory

**Definition**: Let $h$ be a polynomial in $n$ variables, then : 
$\gamma(h,r,R):=\{ v \in \mathbb{Z}^{n} : \vert h(v) \vert \leq r, \Vert v \Vert < R \}$

Let $\omega : \mathbb{Z}^{n} \to \{ 0 , 1\}$ be a function.

**Definition** :  $\omega$ is **algebraically normal** if for all $h$  polynomial and $\forall r \geq 0$ s. t. $\vert \gamma(h,r,\infty) \vert = \infty$ : 
$$ \lim\limits_{R \to \infty}
\frac{\vert \omega^{-1}(0) \cap \gamma(h,r,R) \vert}{\vert \gamma(h,r,R) \vert} = \frac{1}{2}
$$

> Is there such an *algebraically normal* function $\omega$, for all $n \geq 2$ ?

**Remark on groups** : This question could be generalized by replacing $\mathbb{Z}^{n}$ by a countable subset of an Euclidean space $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ or an Hyperbolic space $\mathbb{H}^{n}$ (which are diffeomorphic), or also a separable Hilbert space $H$ (by taking $h$ a polynomial in finitely many variables). As an application, a coarsely embeddable [finitely generated group](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generating_set_of_a_group#Finitely_generated_group) $\Gamma$ (with its [word metric](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Word_metric)) into $\mathbb{R}^{n}$, $\mathbb{H}^{n}$ or $H$, could be called **algebraically normal** if there is such an embedding, admitting an algebraically normal function $\omega$.
The question becomes :  Is there an *algebraically normal* group ?

Comment: [Cross-posted on MSE](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/448685/is-there-an-algebraically-normal-function-from-mathbbz2-to-0-1)

Comment: When you say "real algebraic curve", do you mean "function defined by an ordered pair of polynomials"?  That is not the usual definition of real algebraic curve.

Comment: @S.Carnahan, I mean a function from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}^{2}$ whose range is the zeros of a polynomial in two variables **or** defined by an ordered pair of polynomials in one parameter. Is there a name for this class of curves ?

Comment: Your second case essentially contains your first: If $f(t)$ and $g(t)$ are two polynomials in one parameter, then there is a nonzero polynomial $h$ so that $h(f(t), g(t))=0$. Moreover, the real points of $h(x,y)=0$ will be the image of $(f,g)$, plus finitely many additional points.

Comment: It seems like it would be simpler to look at nonzero polynomials $h$ and define $\gamma(h,r,R)$ to $\{ (x,y) \in \mathbb{Z}^2 : |h(x,y)| < r, \ x^2 + y^2 < R^2 \}$ and then look at $\lim_{R \to \infty} \#(\gamma(h,r,R) \cap \omega^{-1}(0))/\#\gamma(h,r,R)$.

Comment: Thank you @DavidSpeyer, it is in fact simpler and it seems essentially equivalent, I will edit the post.

Comment: Could the *downvoter* and *closer* explain what's the problem ? Thanks (note that the last remark on *groups*, is not essential in this post).

Comment: It seems like $\omega(x,y) = \frac12 + \frac12 (-1)^{\lfloor (\log(x^2+y^2+1))^2 \rfloor}$ works reasonably well.

Comment: Thank you @S.Carnahan for this explicit example. I'm agree with you , it seems there are uncountably many "random" functions like this which are algebraically normal, but can you prove it for your example?

Comment: @S.Carnahan It seems reasonable, but it also seems hard to prove; it will at least require the transcendence of $e$. The only solutions to $|x^2 - xy - y^2| \leq 1$ are consecutive Fibonnaci numbers $(F_{n+1}, F_n)$. So, in this region, $\log(x^2+y^2+1)^2$ is exponentially close to $\left( (2n) \log \tau + \log((\tau^2+1)/\sqrt{5}) \right)^2$, where $\tau$ is the Golden ratio. If $\log \tau$ and $\log((\tau^2+1)/\sqrt{5}$ were rational, you would lose.

Comment: It is not obvious to me that an example of the form $(x-\alpha y)(x -\beta y)$, with $\alpha, \beta $ irrational and carefully chosen, does not provide a counterexample.  The small values will be approximately exponentially spaced, so maybe we can control the $n$th example via the $n$th digit of $\alpha$ and $\beta$ to force most of them to lie in the $0$-set.

Comment: @S.Carnahan A much worse example: Consider the polynomial $x^2 (y-\pi x)$. Last I knew, it was open whether the irrationality measure of $\pi$ was greater than or less than $3$. So we don't know whether there are infinitely many solutions (other than $(0, \ast)$) to $|x^2 (y-\pi x) | < 1$. It seems therefore unlikely that we know ANY bound on how fast such pairs $(x_n, y_n)$ could grow, and therefore unlikely that we can find a function $\omega$ for which we can prove that $\omega(x_n, y_n) \bmod 1$ is equidistributed.

Comment: Okay, I'm reasonably convinced that $\omega$ cannot exist.  I think $(x^2 + y^2)(y-ax-b)$ might be a slightly better choice of polynomial, though.

Comment: Wouldn't such a polynomial run into the problem that the expected number of integral points with small evaluations is finite? So to get infinitely many the polynomial must be quite special, and that impedes your ability to mess with $\omega$.

Comment: I believe I have a proof that there is no coloring for $\mathbb{Z}^2$; see update below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\def\ZZ{\mathbb{Z}}\def\RR{\mathbb{R}}$I suspect this is false! At least, I'll show that a similar statement is false for $\ZZ^4$ and I'll sketch how I think a similar construction should work for $\ZZ^2$.

Fix a coloring $\omega : \ZZ^4 \to \{ 0, 1 \}$. Define a directed graph whose vertices are quadruples $(p,q,p',q') \in \ZZ_{\geq 0}^4$ obeying $p q' - q p' = \pm 1$, $p \leq p'$, $q \leq q'$ and where there is an edge $(p,q, p', q') \to (p', q', p'', q'')$ if there is a positive integer $a$ such that $(p'', q'') = a (p', q') + (p,q)$.

**Case 1** There is some vertex $(p,q,p',q')$ all of whose descendents are of the opposite color from it.

Then, for $a > 0$, the sequence of vertices  $(p', q', a p' + p, a q'+q)$ is monochromatic. We can describe points of the form $(p', q', a p' + p, a q'+q)$ as
$$\left\{ (w,x,y,z) : (w-p')^2 + (x-q')^2 + \left( p' (z-q) - q' (y-p) \right)^2 < 1 \right\}.$$
(Since $\det \left( \begin{smallmatrix} p & p' \\ q & q' \end{smallmatrix} \right) = \pm 1$, we see that $GCD(p',q')=1$ so the condition that $a$ is integral comes for free.) So, if we following this inequality in the direction of large $z$, all the points have the same color.

**Case 2** There is an infinite monochromatic path starting from $(1,0,0,1)$.

Let the vertices on this path be $(p_{n-1}, q_{n-1}, p_n, q_n)$ with 
$$(p_{n+1}, q_{n+1}) = a_n (p_n, q_n) + (p_{n-1}, q_{n-1}).$$

Let $\alpha$ be the value of the continued fraction $a_0+1/(a_1+1/(a_2+1/(\cdots)))$. Then $p_i/q_i$ are the convergents of $\alpha$. (A good reference for all the facts I am using about continued fractions is Chapter X in Hardy and Wright, *Introduction to the Theory of Numbers*.)

We now quote Theorem 172 from Hardy and Wright:

> Suppose that $\zeta$ is a real number $>1$, that $P$, $Q$, $R$, $S$ are integers with $Q>S>0$ and $PS-QR = \pm 1$, and $\alpha = (P \zeta+R)/(Q \zeta+S)$. Then $P/Q$ and $R/S$ are consecutive convergents of $\alpha$. Conversely, if $P/Q$ and $R/S$ are consecutive convergents in lowest terms, then there is a $\zeta$ such that these conditions hold.

Although Hardy and Wright don't point it out, the condition $PS-QR = \pm 1$ forces $GCD(P,Q) = GCD(R,S)=1$, so we get to conclude not only that $P/Q = p_n/q_n$ and $R/S = p_{n+1}/q_{n+1}$ as fractions, but actually that $(P,Q,R,S) = (p_n, q_n, p_{n+1}, q_{n+1})$. Also, they don't state the converse, but they are proving it.

We restate the hypotheses of their theorem:

> The quadruple $(P,Q,R,S)$ is of the form $(p_n, q_n, p_{n+1}, q_{n+1})$ if and only if $Q>S>0$, $PS-QR = \pm 1$ and $(R-\alpha S)/(Q\alpha - P) > 1$.

We can rewrite $u>1$ as $|1-(u-1)/(1+(u-1)^2)| < 1$ so

> The quadruple $(P,Q,R,S)$ is of the form $(p_n, q_n, p_{n+1}, q_{n+1})$ if and only if $Q>S>0$ and 
>   $$ ((PS-QR)^2-1)^2 + (1-(u-1)/(1+(u-1)^2))^2 <1$$
>   where $u = (R-\alpha S)/(Q\alpha - P)$.

This is an inequality of rational functions, but $F/G < 1$ is equivalent to $FG < G^2$. So we have a polynomial inequality with real coefficients which, together with $Q>S>0$, encodes that $(P,Q,R,S)$ is of the form $(p_n, q_n, p_{n+1}, q_{n+1})$. By construction, this means that as we go to $\infty$ along points satisfying this polynomial inequality and lying in the cone $Q>S>0$, we will see only one color for $\omega$.

---

If we wanted to work the same trick for $\ZZ^2$, we would need an inequality for two variables which forces $(p,q)$ to be of the form $p_n/q_n$. Theorem 184 in Hardy and Wright looks good:

> If $\left| \alpha - \frac{p}{q} \right| < \frac{1}{2 q^2}$, then $p/q$ is a convergent.

But it's a trap! This forces $p/q = p_n/q_n$, but it doesn't force $p/q$ to be in lowest terms. I suspect sufficient cleverness could route around this, but I didn't see how.

**UPDATE** This is also false for $\ZZ^2$. I don't have the energy to write down a complete proof, but here is the sketch.

**Case 1** There are slopes $0 < m_1 < m_2$ and a radius $R$ such that the region
$$\left\{ (x,y) : m_1 < \frac{y}{x} < m_2, \ x^2+y^2 > R^2, \ GCD(x,y)=1 \right\}$$
is monochromatic. Then we can find a fraction $p/q$ with $m_1 < p/q < m_2$. All points on the line $py-qx=1$ for $y>>0$ will lie in the above region, so we have a monochromatic ray.

**Case 2** Every region as above is bi-colored.

Mimicing fedja's argument [here](https://mathoverflow.net/a/139260/297), recursively build an $a$ so that all sufficiently large solutions to $|x^5 - a^5 y^5| <1$ have the same color.

Comment: Thank you @DavidSpeyer for this very nice answer ! Do you suspect the non-existence of an "algebraically normal" coloring for $\mathbb{Z}^{4}$ independent of the choice of a coarse embedding (see the remarks on groups) ? If so, the group $\mathbb{Z}^{4}$ would be non-"algebraically normal". Do you suspect the existence of "algebraically normal" groups ?

Answer (score 2):

It is possible that the OP intended $h$ to have integer coefficients. If so, the answer is yes. More generally, the answer is "yes" if we restrict $h$ to any countable list of polynomials.

Let $p: \mathbb{Z}^2 \to \mathbb{Z}_{\geq 0}$ be an injective polynomial; such polynomials are constructed [here](http://zacharyabel.com/papers/Favorite-Problem_A07_HCMR.pdf). I will show that, if we restrict $h$ to a countable list of polynomials, then $(1/2) + (1/2) (-1)^{\lfloor \phi p(x,y) \rfloor}$ works for almost all real numbers $\phi$.

We have the following [Theorem of Bernstein](http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/BF01456856):

> If $b_n$ is a sequence of distinct integers then, for almost all $\theta$,  the sequence $\theta b_n \bmod 1$ is [equidistributed](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equidistributed_sequence).

(Bernstein's paper is in German, but the statement is repeated on the Wikipedia page for [equidistributed](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equidistributed_sequence).) Since a union of countably many sets of measure zero is of measure zero, this shows:

> Let $\mathcal{B}$ be a countable collection of sequences of distinct integers. (I.e. each sequence in $\mathcal{B}$ is a sequence of distinct integers.) Then, for almost all $\theta$, for all $(b_1, b_2, \ldots)$ in $\mathcal{B}$, the sequence $\theta b_n \bmod 1$ is equidistributed.

For every polynomial $h$ with integer coefficients, and every integer $r$, such that there are infinitely many solutions to $|h(x,y)| \leq r$, order those solutions in order of increasing $x^2+y^2$, breaking ties in some manner. Applying $p$ then turns this into a sequence of distinct integers. Find $\theta$ as above and put $\phi = 2\theta$. Then the integer $\lfloor \phi p(x,y) \rfloor$ is equally often even and odd in each of these sequences.